# WiX: Implementing Major Upgrade in WiX 4 for an installer build with WiX 3

Tags: wix, wix3, wix3.11, wix4

I have had Major Upgrades working in a WiX v3.11 installer, following [this tutorial](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/howtos/updates/major_upgrade/) and learning [quite a bit](https://blog.crusy.net/wix-upgrade-pitfalls/) (German only).

But now WiX 4 is here which I want to try out for an update from 2.0.0 (build with WiX 3.11) to 2.1.0 (build with WiX 4.0.3). And I see that the mentioned tutorial is somewhat outdated:

- `Product` element is `Package` now, so `Product.Version` is `Package.Version` now
- `Product.Id` is `Package.ProductCode` now

I would have thought that – besides the naming – everything works as before. So I bumped my version value from 2.0.0 to 2.1.0 and generated a new `Package.ProductCode` GUID (instead of `Product.Id`), just as said in step 2 of the tutorial. But my 2.1 product is installed additionally to 2.0:

[image: v2.1.0 and v2.0.0 in parallel]

I was not able to find an Upgrade tutorial especially for WiX 4, so my question is: What do I have to know to make this work?

**UPDATE:** I was able to verify with a second installer that our set-up is working. This is **NOT** an issue of WiX, nor WiX 3 vs. 4! But nevertheless this *is* a problem, so I tried to get some debug information by upgrade both products by running `msiexec.exe /i each.msi /L*VX debug.log`. Now in the working installer's log I see

```
MSI (c) (0C:2C) [01:08:30:365]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
Action 1:08:30: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 1:08:30: FindRelatedProducts.
FindRelatedProducts: Found application: {02494A83-9693-3A7E-B7F0-BC314326DD43}
MSI (c) (0C:2C) [01:08:30:370]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED property. Its value is '{02494A83-9693-3A7E-B7F0-BC314326DD43}'.
MSI (c) (0C:2C) [01:08:30:370]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MIGRATE property. Its value is '{02494A83-9693-3A7E-B7F0-BC314326DD43}'.
Action ended 1:08:30: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
```

while in the not working installer's log this reads:

```
MSI (c) (EC:58) [00:59:33:824]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
Action 0:59:33: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 0:59:33: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 0:59:33: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
```

I read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/findrelatedproducts-action) that `FindRelatedProducts` considers UpgradeCode, version, language. All of these are unchanged between 2.0 and 2.1 in both projects. So it remains unclear, when and why WiX 4 does not find "related" aka previous WiX 3 installations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/findrelatedproducts-action) says

> The FindRelatedProducts action uses **the UpgradeCode property and the version and language information** authored into the Upgrade table to detect installed products affected by the pending upgrade.

But that's not sufficient. It may find a "related" product, but skips that anyways – e.g. if that product installed per-user (=registered under `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Installer\Products\`), while the upgrade is installed per-machine (=registered under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\`). This is the "Scope" in WiX.

You can see if this happens by enabling debugging (`<Property Id="MsiLogging" Value="voicewarmupx"/>`, logs are stored in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\temp`) and searching for

> FindRelatedProducts: current install is per-machine.  Related install for product '{FA3BF64B-3497-3605-AAC4-9210007BF8D6}' is per-user.  Skipping...

So the answer here is: Make sure to install both the product and its update in the same scope! You can do so by using the `Scope` attribute of the `Package` element, see [here](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/schema/wxs/package/#attributes).

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide enough code to really know what is going on but it generally sounds like you've done the necessary work.

I covered upgrades in [S1:E4 of the Deployment Dojo - Out with the Old. In with the New](https://robmensching.com/deployment-dojo/episodes/s1/e4/out-with-the-old-in-with-the-new/). In the end you'll get something like:

```xml
<Package UpgradeCode='{GUID-MUST-NOT-CHANGE}' Name='Stuff' Manufacturer='Me' Version='2.0.3'>
   <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage='Cannot downgrade' />
```

Comment: Thank you. I could verify in a different project that our approach is working and WiX 4 indeed works identically (besides naming). There has to be a problem with our UpgradeCode, not with the procedure itself. I'll leave this question here at least until I found the actual reason.

Comment: #fyi: You've been right, I did not provide the important information (but neither did Microsoft, kind of): The product was installed per-user, the update per-machine, see my answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Ahh, yes, the dreaded cross-install-scope registration. I forget about checking that. More of your code might have helped see that.